# Use ReflectiveTypeAdapter for Currency Object

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson, deserialization

In older versions of Gson (<2.5.0) the reflective type adapter was used for deserializing java.util.Currency objects. So I have something like : "{"currencyCode": "USD"}" persisted in a database.

Now, I want to bump up Gson to a higher version (which has introduced a new CurrencyTypeAdapterFactory - that is no longer able to deserialize the object from my database).

Is there any way that I could enforce Gson to use the same reflective type adapter for the Currency class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use something like this to provide a specific type adapter binding for the required class :

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(Currency.class, getCurrencyTypeAdapter());
gson = builder.create();

TypeAdapter<Currency> getCurrencyTypeAdapter() {
    ConstructorConstructor constructorConstructor = new ConstructorConstructor(Collections.emptyMap());
    JsonAdapterAnnotationTypeAdapterFactory jsonAdapterFactory = new JsonAdapterAnnotationTypeAdapterFactory(constructorConstructor);
    ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory reflectiveTypeAdapterFactory = new ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory(
        constructorConstructor, FieldNamingPolicy.IDENTITY, Excluder.DEFAULT, jsonAdapterFactory);
    return reflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(new Gson(), new TypeToken<Currency>() {});
}
```

This is a work-around. Ideally, you should fix your usage of Currency class and utilise the default type adapter that internally uses : Currency.getInstance()